# Preencher chave estrangeira com valor da chave primária

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com ASP.Net MVC e NHibernate, eu tenho um cadastro de empresa e um cadastro de cliente, onde uma empresa pode ter vários clientes. As classes já estão mapeadas para o banco junto com seu relacionamento. Só que a chave estrangeira de cliente que deveria pegar o `Id` da chave primária de empresa esta `null`, não estou conseguindo implementar uma lógica para que quando for gravar meu cliente ele consiga pegar a chave primária da empresa. Meu DAO está assim:

```
using SistemaOCW.Entidade;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SistemaOCW.Infra;
using NHibernate;

namespace SistemaOCW.DAO
{
    public class ClienteDAO
    {
        private ISession session;


        public ClienteDAO(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
        }    

        public void Adiciona(Cliente cliente)
        {
            NHibernate.ITransaction transacao = session.BeginTransaction();
            session.Save(cliente);
            transacao.Commit();
        }    

        // public Cliente BuscaPorId(int id)
        //  {
        //  return session.Get<Cliente>(id);
        //  }
    }
}
```

E meu *controller* esta assim:

```
using NHibernate;
using SistemaOCW.DAO;
using SistemaOCW.Entidade;
using SistemaOCW.Infra;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;    

namespace SistemaOCW.Controllers
{
    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {    
        public ActionResult Form()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Adiciona(Cliente cliente)
        {    
            ISession session = NHibernateHelper.AbreSession();

            ClienteDAO dao = new ClienteDAO(session);

            dao.Adiciona(cliente);
            session.Close();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }        
    }
}
```

EmpresaDAO:

```
using SistemaOCW.Entidade;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SistemaOCW.Infra;
using NHibernate;
using SistemaOCW.Controllers;

namespace SistemaOCW.DAO
{
    public class EmpresaDAO
    {
        private ISession session;

        public EmpresaDAO(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
        }

        public void Adiciona(Empresa empresa)
        {
            NHibernate.ITransaction transacao = session.BeginTransaction();
            session.Save(empresa);
            transacao.Commit();
        }

        // public Cliente BuscaPorId(int id)
        //  {
        //      return session.Get<Cliente>(id);
        //  }
    }
}
```

Entidade Cliente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SistemaOCW.Entidade
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int Codcliente { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cnpj { get; set; }
        public virtual string Endereco { get; set; }
        public virtual string Bairro { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cidade { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cep { get; set; }
        public virtual string Telefone { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Contato { get; set; }
        public virtual Empresa empresa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entidade Empresa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SistemaOCW.Entidade
{
    public class Empresa
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cnpj { get; set; }
        public virtual string Endereco { get; set; }
        public virtual string Bairro { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cidade { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cep { get; set; }
        public virtual string Telefone { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Contato { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mapeamento da entidade Empresa:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                       assembly="SistemaOCW"
                       namespace="SistemaOCW.Entidade">
      <class name ="Empresa">
        <id name ="Id">
            <generator class ="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Nome"/>
        <property name="Cnpj"/>
        <property name="Endereco"/>
        <property name="Bairro"/>
        <property name="Cidade"/>
        <property name="Cep"/>
        <property name="Telefone"/>
        <property name="Email"/>
        <property name="Contato"/> 
        <bag name="Clientes">
          <key column= "EmpresaId"/>
          <one-to-many class="Cliente"/>  
        </bag>
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

View de cadastro do Cliente:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Form";
}

<h2>Cadastro Cliente</h2>

<form action="@Url.Action("Adiciona", "Cliente")" method="post">
    <label>
        Codigo:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Codcliente" />
        Nome:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Nome" />
         CNPJ:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Cnpj" />
         Endereco:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Endereco" />
         Bairro:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Bairro" />
         Cidade:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Cidade" />
         CEP:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Cep" />
         Telefone:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Telefone" />
         Email:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Email" />
         Contato:
        <input type="text" name="cliente.Contato" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Adicionar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Eu precisava que tu comentasse o que acontece, porque, eu não entendi a sua duvida !!! Dá erros, acontece além de não trazer o código alguma coisa a mais !!! ?

Answer (score 1):

No mapeamento você pode configurar para o NHibernate gerar o ID automaticamente para você, então terá algo assim se você estiver usando **Nhibernate**:

```
<id name="Id">
    <generator class="identity"/>
</id>
```

No mapeamento você terá algo assim se você estiver usando **Fluent Nhibernate**:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
```

Verifique se você está com essa configuração correta, ou caso você configurou para gerar o ID de outra forma (que não seja automática por exemplo).

Se essa configuração está correta e isso ainda não resolve seu problema, coloque os arquivos de mapeamento para que possamos tentar ajudar.

Comment: Eu nao estou fazendo uso de Fluent Nhibernate, como estou aprendendo agora resolvi fazer no Nhibernate mesmo, segue os mapeamentos e classes, ele gera no cliente o EmpresaId mais ele vem null.